# Dúvida Soma com união?

Tags: php, mysql, sum, union

Boa noite sou novo e estou com uma dúvida. Tenho uma tabela com 2 campos forma de pagamento 1 e forma de pagamento 2 e valores recebidos 1 e 2.

Montei essa consulta para totalizar e contar.

```
SELECT empresa, SUM(valorrecebido) as Total, COUNT(empresa) as Quantidade FROM material WHERE formapagamento = ('Em Aberto') AND (data BETWEEN ('2022-04-24') AND ('2022-04-24')) GROUP by empresa UNION SELECT empresa, SUM(valorrecebido2) as Total, COUNT(empresa) as Quantidade FROM material WHERE formapagamento2 = ('Em Aberto') AND (data BETWEEN ('2022-04-24') AND ('2022-04-24')) GROUP by empresa
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de juntar as empresas e somar os totais e quantidade.

Está aparecendo 2 vezes a mesma empresa. Teria ser uma vez só a PTC COELHO ME e somar os totais e a quantidade

Teria que ficar assim:

Empresa              Total         Quantidade
PTC Coelho ME        108.00        3
TRANSPARAIBA          10.00        1

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Select empresa , sum(total) from (select ....by empresa) group by empresa , ponha o código na tag de {} code por favor

Comment: Benilson havia tentado isso mas ele soma recebido1 e recebido2 sendo qualquer outra forma sem ser em aberto. Ele deu o total de 114 e o correto é 108

Comment: @JandersonLucena Sim, até apaguei o comentário, você pode colocar essa sua consulta atual em uma subconsulta e somar e agrupar novamente.

Comment: @Benilson poderia me ajudar por favor. Não entendo muito mas estou tentando.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar sua consulta atual em uma [subconsulta](https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-subqueries/40134), simulando uma tabela e fazer uma nova consulta, em cima dos dados retornados da subconsulta, fazendo novos agrupamentos e somas.

Texto extraído do link: "Uma Subquery (também conhecida como SUBCONSULTA ou SUBSELECT) é uma instrução do tipo SELECT dentro de outra instrução SQL. Desta forma, se torna possível efetuar consultas que de outra forma seriam extremamente complicadas ou impossíveis de serem feitas de outra forma."

Obs.: Acredito que o `union` deveria ser substituído pelo `union all`, pois caso os dados retornados pelo union tenham os mesmo valores retornados na consulta antecedente ao union, eles serão descartados, com union all isso não acontece.

```
select subconsulta.empresa, 
    sum(subconsulta.Total) as Total, 
    sum(subconsulta.Quantidade) as Quantidade /* aqui passa a ser sum ao invés de count */
from ( 
    (
        select
            empresa,
            SUM(valorrecebido) as Total,
            COUNT(empresa) as Quantidade
        from material
        where formapagamento = ('Em Aberto')
            and (data between ('2022-04-24') and ('2022-04-24'))
        group by empresa
    ) union (
        select
            empresa,
            SUM(valorrecebido2) as Total,
            COUNT(empresa) as Quantidade
        from material
        where formapagamento2 = ('Em Aberto')
            and (data between ('2022-04-24') and ('2022-04-24'))
        group by empresa
    ) 
) as subconsulta
group by subconsulta.empresa
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda.